# Android: vertical image scrolling with image array constantly changing

Tags: android, bitmap, scrollview, vertical-scrolling, scroll-position

I have an array of bitmaps which are generated inside the code(not taken from assets, card, web etc.) and there are around 50 (this number is not a constant) bitmaps which need to be in that array. At first I tried to create all the bitmaps at once which obviously resulted in outOfMemmory error. Because it is mandatory for images to be in exact order one after another based on id I created variable bitmapID which is increased when one bitmap is created and left the image creating only when it needs to be displayed on the screen based on that bitmapID variable.

So first solution(which worked) was filling a LinearLayout which is inside ScrollView with ImageView(s). Inside activity onCreate() call method fillScreen(int how_many_times) which would fill screen with images as many times as variable how_many_times intended. In my demo app I had the tablet screen filled 3 times. fillScreen(int how_many_times) is working on the loop calling loadBitmap(int bitmapID) which is responsible for creating single bitmap based on given id. The created bitmap was saved in array of imageHolder objects. imageHolder object besides bitmap and id also had scroll_start and scroll_end parameters indicating their scroll positions. For example the first imageHolder would have scroll_start = 0 and scroll_end = 500 while second imageHolder would have scroll_start = 500 and scroll_end = 800. Activity has implementation of onScrollChanged(scrollView, int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy) to react to scrolling and add images at the bottom of screen and remove from top. So the implementation worked liked this:

```
if (y > arrayOfImageHolders.get(1).getScroll_end() && removeEnabled) 
{
//removes one image view from beginning of LinearLayout
removeFromBegining();
scrollView.scrollTo(0, arrayOfImageHolders.get(1).getScroll_start());
}

if (y > arrayOfImageHolders.get(arrayOfImageHolders.size() - 1).getScroll_start() && fillEnabled) 
{

//Adds image views at the end of LinearLayout                   
fillScreenEnd(1);

}
```

With this implementation the scrolling was smooth and I had almost no jumping in scroll when images were added or removed. scroll_start and scroll_end values were always updated after adding or removing image on all imageHolder objects. So this implementation worked on forward scrolling, but I needed it to work in the same way for backwards scrolling too. So I added if cases to react to backwards scrolling and in my head it had to work as perfectly as forward scrolling. Backwards scrolling if cases:

```
if (y > arrayOfImageHolders.get(arrayOfImageHolders.size() - 1).getScroll_start() && fillEnabled) 
{

//Adds image views at the end of LinearLayout                   
fillScreenEnd(1);

}
else if(y < arrayOfImageHolders.get(1).getScroll_start()) && fillEnabled && y < oldy)
{
//Add image views at the beginning of LinearLayout
fillScreenStart(1);

}

if (y > arrayOfImageHolders.get(1).getScroll_end() && removeEnabled) 
{
//removes one image view from beginning of LinearLayout
removeFromBegining();
scrollView.scrollTo(0, arrayOfImageHolders.get(1).getScroll_start());
}
else if(y < arrayOfImageHolders.get(arrayOfImageHolders.size()-2).getScroll_start() && removeEnabled && y < oldy)
{
//removes one image view from end of LinearLayout
removeFromEnd();

}
```

I tried including scrollTo() in different places, but it does not work anywhere. The scroll just keeps on moving when something is added at the beginning or removed from end. I want to keep scroll position constant no matter if scrollView becomes bigger or smaller. Any ideas on how to make it happen? Or maybe any other ideas on how to implement this kind of scrollView?

I also tried ListView with custom adapter and implementation of onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) and tried changing the arrayOfImageHolders by removing and adding items and calling notifyDataSetChange(), but could not get the position of the screen stable when removing or adding either.

To make this case and problem more clear try imagining casino slot machine. There is a list of images which remain in order all the time but only one is showed on the screen. And you can roll the wheel in both directions and even if you add some images to the wheel or remove some the image you see on the screen remains the same.

For me it looks like a complicated problem so any ideas (not just concrete solutions) are appreciated.